# How to Configure Custom AOT Compilation Options in Angular's angular.json?

Tags: angular, angular.json

I'm working on an Angular project and looking to optimize my application's performance using Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation. I understand that the angular.json file holds the project configuration, but I'm unsure how to customize AOT compilation settings for my specific needs. Could someone guide me on how to modify the angular.json file to achieve this? For instance, how would I configure options like optimization level or specify custom transformers?

Here's a sample snippet of my current angular.json:

https://jsongrid.com/?data=2ef9742e-4486-4bb0-aab5-ea0baf2923f1

I'm particularly curious about the properties under the "aot" key. Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Angular.json configuration:

I tried basic customization like setting the optimiztionLevel = 1.

I'm looking to optimize the performance further with custom transformers.

Comment: AFAIK the `aot` flag only accepts a boolean type. What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Please provide the Angular version you are using. Also, please add the angular.json within the post rather than an external link.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I use angular 11. I'm looking to optimization build performance with AOT if possible.

Comment: @Geo242 I mentioned the angular version in above comment. The JSON config was too big, so I've put on a separate website and link it here.